# How to bind selected value to dropdown list in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a Dropdown list with a list of courses ..for example, one student selected one course and saved all the details. At the time of edit how we can bind selected course to drop down in Angular 4
anyone help me, please.

Comment: Right now i'm working with angularjs 4, who said like  
There is no angularjs 4 ?

Comment: Well !! yes there is no angularjs 4 but there is angular 4 . just for the information . Secondly could you please post some code here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
<select class='select-option' required [(ngModel)]='optionSelected' (ngModelChange)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
    <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of options' [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

So whenever option is changed , the value is stored in `optionSelected` in your ts,

```
options = [1, 2, 3];
optionSelected: any;

onOptionsSelected(event){
 console.log(event); //option value will be sent as event
}
```

(fixed functionName in template and the ts to be the same)

Answer (score 1):

```
(ngModelChange)='onOptionsSelected($event)'

onOptionsSelected($event){
 console.log($event);
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your contribution, please note that the rules say you shouldn't write code only answers. Please read [Help Center > Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and try to give only [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

add 2 ngModel in that one is for binding and another for selected value it is worked for me

Comment: Can you add some code to your answer to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try simple

```
 <select (change)="showEntity($event.target.value)">
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
```

In .ts file

```
showEntity(e){
console.log(e)
}
```